# using ANSI C libraries for STM32 programs

Tags: stm32

In the internet, I often find examples of the source codes for programming STM32 MCUs at register-level. Strangely, some of those source codes include "#include < stdint.h >". In general, is it possible to include ANSI C libraries in the source codes for STM32?

Here is [an example](https://github.com/travisg/stm32) of such a C project.

Comment: stdint.h is not a *library*

Comment: If your development tools include the standard libraries, you can include them. That would mean including their headers in your source files that reference them, and linking the libraries in your build process.

Comment: What exactly is strange with using stdint.h? All professional embedded systems have been doing that for 20 years.

Comment: You can include whatever you want. math, string, libtiff as you mentioned. Just be aware of the memory and flash footprint. There are people doing image recognition on ARMs

Comment: @Lundin I cannot imagine what would happen, when STM32 tries to print strings to the standard output, or access files. Is it possible to compile codes with such functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You should definitely be aware of their possibilities.

Check the documentation for when you are using the ARM Toolchain.
https://developer.arm.com/docs/dui0475/l/the-arm-c-and-c-libraries
https://static.docs.arm.com/dui0475/l/DUI0475L_libraries_user_guide.pdf

Or for GNU:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc.pdf

You can also find info in the [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) docs, such as [stdint.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).